# arcpy: program crashes on intersect

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis, arcpy

I am writing a program that takes the input of two shape files that were exported with pgsql2shp.exe and does the intersection between them. Here is my code

```
print sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
intersection = ''
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]], intersection, "ALL")
```

where sys.argv[1] and [2] are absolute paths to the .shp files being intersected. e.g. U:\proj\a.shp and U:\proj\b.shp

It compiles but when run gives

> Traceback (most recent call last): line 45, in 
>       arcpy.Intersect_analysis([sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]], out_path, "ALL")  line 289, in Intersect
>       raise e arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000735: Output Feature Class: Value is
>   required Failed to execute (Intersect).

How do I fix it and where do I access the return value? I want to put the result in a table in a database. I'm new to Python, ArcPy and GIS.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the name of the output feature class to be an empty string. Try:

```
intersection = "Intersect_Output"
```

The output feature class (here, Intersect_Output) will be written to the geodatabase you're working in.

Comment: Now it gives `arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Intersect_Output
Failed to execute (Intersect).`

Comment: Have you set arcpy.env.workspace (i.e., arcpy.env.workspace = <path_to_your_geodatabase>)?

Comment: Nope I'm new and don't know what that means?

Comment: You'll need to specify the path to the geodatabase you're working in. You ought to review the [code snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) that ESRI provides in their help pages to clarify.